# Lerna cannot find peer dependency of symlinked module

Tags: apollo-server, lerna, monorepo

Hmm, not sure if this is a bug in lerna or if *I am doing it wrong*. I have a case where I have a lerna monorepo package that has a peerDependency that it is supposed to find in the "consuming" monorepo package:

```
packages
 | - @red/app
 | - @red/gql
```

- `@red/app` has a `dependency` to `@red/gql` and to `graphql`
- `@red/gql` has a `peerDependency` to `graphql`

`@red/gql` makes use of `graphql` (actually it is one of its dependencies that makes use of it and also requires it as a peer dependency) and when I call it from `@red/app` it cannot find `graphql`.

If I do `bootstrap` with the `hoist` option it does work so it appears to me that it cannot find the `graphql` package from `@red/gql` because it is symlinked and it it searching for `graphql` in the wrong folder.